# how to write special query

Tags: sql

this is my table:

[image]

i want to write a query that show me this result :

```
clock_BarCode  code_BDate  Clock_BTime
00001142       1395/11/20    (1094-472)=622
00001147       1395/11/20     549
00001151       1395/11/20     578
00001172       1395/11/20     552
00001187       1395/11/20     649
```

how can i write??

Comment: Max value - min value, for each clock_BarCode? What if different code_BDate values for a clock_BarCode?

Comment: Max value - min value, for each clock_BarCode and each Clock_BDate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming bar code records always come in pairs (or even single), then you can do this with a basic `GROUP BY` query:

```
SELECT t1.Clock_BarCode,
       t1.Clock_BDate,
       t2.Clock_BTime
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Clock_BarCode,
           MAX(Clock_BTime) - MIN(Clock_BTime) AS Clock_BTime
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Clock_BarCode
) t2
    ON t1.Clock_BarCode = t2.Clock_BarCode
```

Comment: hi,thanks but i dont want max(clock_bdate),i have 2 clock_btime for every date and i want the (max(clock_Btime)-min(Clock_Btime))for each day and each clock_barcode